# login en c# con sql :c

Tags: c#, sql

Hola podrian ayudarme estuve trabajando un login en c# con conexion sqlserver
lo que pasa es que ahora estoy trabajando con N-capas y ahora quiero que ese metodo este en una clase y no en el mismo formulario

Aqui en la foto esta mi codigo todo me funciona bien

Lo unico que no es lo que le puse como comentario ya que ese metodo anteriormente estaba en el formulario y lo llamaba desde ahi y no tenia problemas
pero ahora ando pensando como podria llamarlo desde una clase
Estos codigos son para que cuando el usuario sea correcto se cierre la ventana y me muestre la ventana principal
o alguna opcion o sugerencia como puedo hacer? :c

```
/*
                this.Hide();
                FrmMDI mdi = new FrmMDI();
                mdi.FormClosed += (s, args) => this.Close();
                mdi.Show();
                */
```

Y asi llamo a mi metodo desde mi formulario

```
 /*
  private void btnAcceder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            abc.acceder(txtuser, txtpass);

        }
  */
```

[image: Foto]

[image: Aqui esta en donde llamo al metodo en mi formulario]

Comment: Pero que error te da, da más detalles

Comment: No haz pensado en usar javascript ?

Comment: @HatoriHanso porque deberia usar javascript si esta programando en c#?

Comment: Siempre es mejor pegar el codigo y no una foto para copiar y pega tu codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada usar capaz es sacar tu codigo a otro proyecto, no es mas que eso, y debes pensar que necesitas que te devuelva para que vos proceses esa info y realizar dicha accion en consecuencia.

Podrias crear tu servicio de login de esta forma en un archivo separado:

```
public class ServicioLogin
{
   public bool Login(string user, string pass)
   {
      //Realizar tu conexion y verificar si es true o false el login.

      return true; // o false segun tu respuesta.
   }
}
```

Y en tu formulario lo llamas asi:

```
ServicioLogin _Servicio = new ServicioLogin();

dentro de tu boton podrias hacer esto:

if(_Servicio.Login(txtUser.Text, txtPass.Text))
{
 //Si el usuario se logeo bien, lo envias a donde sea,
}
else
{
   //sino le avisas que fue incorrecto.
}
```